# count messages that sent by users in my chat

Tags: php, function, chat

first i have a chat script and every user in my chat have his own profile and some information inside his profile like, country, age, grinder, his photo and his friends, somehow i need to display the count of his all messages that he had sent in chat, and i'll make a new field in his profile ti put this number.

so here i have this function that store messages for users in database.

```
    function userPostChat($content, $snum = ''){
    global $mysqli, $data;
    $lact = calMinutes(3);
    $style = escape($data['bccolor'] . ' ' . $data['bcbold']);
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `my_chat` (post_date, user_id, post_message, post_roomid, type, snum, tcolor) VALUES ('" . time() . "', '{$data['user_id']}', '$content', '{$data['user_roomid']}', 'public', '$snum', '$style')");
    $last_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE my_users SET caction = caction + 1 WHERE user_roomid = '{$data['user_roomid']}' and last_action > '$lact'");
    if($snum != ''){
        $user_post = array(
            'post_id'=> $last_id,
            'type'=> 'public',
            'post_date'=> time(),
            'tcolor'=> $style,
            'post_message'=> $content,
        );
        $post = array_merge($data, $user_post);
        if(!empty($post)){
            return createLog($data, $post);
        }
    }
}
```

i forget to say that function already count messages from all users and store it in column inside my_users table called ' caction ' but this function count the messages for all users in the same time like, if i have 0 points and someone sent a message in chat it will count this message for me and him and all users in chat, and i don't wanna it, i want a function to count messages for every user and display the number.

here is my tables:

Table **my_users**

```
user_id
user_name
password
user_photo
user_email
room_id
caction
```

Table **my_chat**

```
post_id
user_id
post_date
post_message
post_roomid
type
snum
tcolor
```

and here i have my chat_file.php

```
function userPostChatFile($content, $file_name, $type, $file_name2 = ''){
    global $mysqli, $data;
    $lact = calMinutes(3);
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `my_chat` (post_date, user_id, post_message, post_roomid, type, file) VALUES ('" . time() . "', '{$data['user_id']}', '$content', '{$data['user_roomid']}', 'public', '1')");
    $rel = $mysqli->insert_id;
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE my_users SET caction = caction + 1 WHERE user_roomid = '{$data['user_roomid']}' and last_action > '$lact'");
    if($file_name2 != ''){
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `my_upload` (file_name, date_sent, file_user, file_zone, file_type, relative_post) VALUES
        ('$file_name', '" . time() . "', '{$data['user_id']}', 'chat', '$type', '$rel'),
        ('$file_name2', '" . time() . "', '{$data['user_id']}', 'chat', '$type', '$rel')
        ");
    }
    else {
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `my_upload` (file_name, date_sent, file_user, file_zone, file_type, relative_post) VALUES ('$file_name', '" . time() . "', '{$data['user_id']}', 'chat', '$type', '$rel')");
    }
    return true;
}

if(!myAllow($data['allow_image']) || muted() || roomMuted()){ 
    die();
}
if (isset($_FILES["file"])){
    ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
    $info = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = $info['extension'];
    $origin = escape(filterOrigin($info['filename']) . '.' . $extension);
    if ( fileError() ){
        echo 1;
        die();
    }
    if (isImage($extension)){
        $imginfo = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
        if ($imginfo !== false) {

            $width = $imginfo[0];
            $height = $imginfo[1];
            $type = $imginfo['mime'];

            $fname = encodeFileTumb($extension);
            $file_name = $fname['full'];
            $file_tumb = $fname['tumb'];

            move_uploaded_file(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]), "../upload/chat/" . $file_name);

            $source = '../upload/chat/' . $file_name;
            $tumb = '../upload/chat/' . $file_tumb;
            $img_path = $data['domain'] . "/upload/chat/" . $file_name;
            $tumb_path = $data['domain'] . "/upload/chat/" . $file_tumb;

            $create = imageTumb($source, $tumb, $type, 180);
            if(file_exists($source) && file_exists($tumb)){
                $check_tumb = getimagesize($tumb);
                if ($check_tumb !== false) {
                    $myimage = tumbLinking($img_path, $tumb_path);
                    userPostChatFile($myimage, $file_name, 'image', $file_tumb);
                }
                else {
                    $myimage = linking($img_path);
                    userPostChatFile($myimage, $file_name, 'image');
                }
            }
            else {
                $myimage = linking($img_path);
                userPostChatFile($myimage, $file_name, 'image');
            }
            echo 5;
            die();


        }
        else {
            echo 1;
            die();
        }
    }
    else if (isFile($extension)){
        $file_name = encodeFile($extension);
        move_uploaded_file(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]), "../upload/chat/" . $file_name);
        $myfile = $data['domain'] . "/upload/chat/" . $file_name;
        $myfile =  fileProcess($myfile, $origin);
        userPostChatFile($myfile, $file_name, 'file');
        echo 5;
        die();
    }
    else if (isMusic($extension)){
        $file_name = encodeFile($extension);
        move_uploaded_file(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]), "../upload/chat/" . $file_name);
        $myfile = $data['domain'] . "/upload/chat/" . $file_name;
        $myfile =  musicProcess($myfile, $origin);
        userPostChatFile($myfile, $file_name, 'music');
        echo 5;
        die();
    }
    else {
        echo 1;
    }
}
else {
    echo 1;
}
?>
```

so how i can make a function to count messages for each user and store it in column in **my_users** table.

Answer (score 0):

Run this query you will get the number of messages send by each user. You can either display the count on his page or store it somewhere and display it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS no_messages FROM my_chat WHERE user_id = <user id here>
```

Comment: you didn't get what i want, i need to make a php function to store the count of messages that sent by user in a column like, if i sent a message in chat function store 1 if i sent another messages function store 2 in column.